# Служба полнотекстового поиска (full-text search service) и индексирование таблицы

Tags: sql, sql-server, полнотекстовый-поиск

Подскажите, как включить full-text search service и проиндексировать таблицу? Мне необходимо использовать оператор CONTAINS.

Comment: запустить саму службу в менеджере sql сервера, добавить полнотекстовый индекс в таблицу, указав какие поля входят. написать запрос. на какой именно стадии возникает проблема?

Comment: @teran 1) где именно находится эта служба; 2) как именно добавить полнотекстовый индекс

Comment: 1) на машине, где установлен сервер ищите в Пуске [SQL Server Configuration Manager](https://www.mytechmantra.com/LearnSQLServer/SQLArticleImages/SQLServerConfigurationManager/image001.png)

Comment: 2) в SQL Server Managment Studio на таблице правой кнопкой, и там будет [Full text index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ethnt.jpg)